# Cannot find symbol - method: variable(double)

Tags: java, variables, methods, cannot-find-symbol

My program is not close to being finished, but I am stuck because the compiler gives me an error message "cannot find symbol - method years(double)" in the depreciatonTable method the variable years.

-I am sure it is very obvious, but I cannot seem to figure out why the compiler comes up with an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem1
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double AcquisVal, SalvageVal, years;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Problem1 val = new Problem1(); 

    System.out.println("Enter the Acquisition Value: ")  ;

    AcquisVal = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the Salvage Value: ");

    SalvageVal = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the years of useful life(in whole years): ");

    years = scan.nextDouble();

    if (AcquisVal < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Acquisition value cannot be negative"); 
    }
    else if (years < 1){
        System.out.println("Years of useful life must be greater than zero");
    }
    else if (SalvageVal < 0){
        System.out.println("Salvage value cannot be negative");
    }
    else 
        val.depreciationtable(AcquisVal, SalvageVal, years);
}

public double depreciationtable(double years, double AcquisVal, double SalvageVal)
{
    double depreciation, fraction, annDepreciation, AccDepreciation, BookValue;

    while (years > 0)
    {
        fraction = years / (years (years + 1)/ 2);
        years--; 
    }
    depreciation = (AcquisVal - SalvageVal) * fraction;
    return depreciation;
}
}
```

Comment: `years (years + 1)` is the syntax for calling a method called `years`. Are you missing a `*`?

Comment: by the way looks like you are passing the methods in a wrong order

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your logic at

`fraction = years / (years (years + 1)/ 2)`. The `years (years + 1)` part is logically wrong.

Also, look at the [Java Naming conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) to use correct variable/method names.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something basic like that. It was right under my nose.

Comment: Happens :)
Do accept the answer if it solves what you were looking for.

And your naming conventions..look at those too.

Comment: Rectification: 
double depreciation=0.0, fraction=0.0, annDepreciation=0.0,   AccDepreciation=0.0, BookValue=0.0;

fraction = years / (years * (years + 1)/ 2); // This was a problem.